# Merge data from two sources into one destination without duplicates

Tags: ssis, merge

I have data from two different source locations that need to be combined into one. I am assuming I would want to do this with a merge or a merge join, but I am unsure of what exactly I need to do.

`Table 1` has the same fields as `Table 2` but the data is different which is why I would like to combine them into one destination table. I am trying to do this with SSIS, but I have never had to merge data before.

The other issue that i have is that some of the data is duplicated between the two. How would I only keep 1 of the duplicated records?

Comment: What's the end result? Table 1 and 2 are mirrors of each other or are you populating a different destination? What's your data volume look like? Any other constraints we should know about? What's your survival strategy? Table 1, Customer Id X indicates name is Bob. Table 2, Customer Id X, indicates name is Robert. Which one survives? What if a row exists in Table 1 but not in 2, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an entirely new table which will need to be updated again every time Table 1 or 2 changes, you could use a combination of views and UNIONs. In other words create a view that is the result of a UNION query between your two tables. To get rid of duplicates you could group by whatever column uniquely identifies each record.

Here is a UNION query using Group By to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT
    MAX (ID) AS ID,
    NAME,
    MAX (going)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID :: VARCHAR,
            NAME,
            going
        FROM
            facebook_events
        UNION
            SELECT
                ID :: VARCHAR,
                NAME,
                going
            FROM
                events
    ) AS merged_events
GROUP BY
    NAME
```

*(Postgres not SSIS, but same concept)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  Merge and Sort , Use union all Sort. because Merge transform need two sorted input and performance will be decreased

1)Give  Source1 & Source2 as input to UnionALL Transformation
2) Give Output of UnionALL transfromation to Sort transformation and check remove duplicate keys.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a pretty classic merge. Create your source and destination connections. Put in a Data Flow task. Put both sources into the Data Flow. Make sure the sources are both sorted and connect them to a Merge. You can either add in a Sort transformation between the connection and the Merge or sort them using a query when you pull them in. It's easier to do it with a query if that's possible in your situation. Put a Sort transformation after the Merge and check the "Remove rows with duplicate sort values" box. That will take care of any duplicates you have. Connect the Sort transformation to the data destination.

You can do this without SSIS, too.